# Add more desktop effects to OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

Is it possible to add more desktop effects to OSX like in compiz?

Answer (score 3):

### No.

Unfortunately, it isn't possible.

Comment: "Unfortunately"?

Comment: @Daniel: Well, since the asker wanted it, it is unfortunate. It's the last thing I'd want to do to my Mac, though.